# How to get the text content for the following xml code

Tags: java, xml-parsing

```
    Above one is the XML file. I need to get the value for the Google analytics from the above xml file
```

I need to get the output as      from the above xml. I have tried the following code but it's not showing any output
Can you help me on this

Above one is the XML file. I need to get the value for the Google analytics from the above xml file

```
public class Xml {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\VAMSIKRISHNA\\Desktop\\Apache Poi\\appConfig.plist")));

        NodeList nodeList=document.getElementsByTagName("key");
        NodeList nodeList1=document.getElementsByTagName("string");

        for (int i=0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<nodeList1.getLength();j++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                Node node1=nodeList1.item(j);
                if (node.getNodeName()=="GA") {
                    System.out.println("Nodename"+node1.getNodeName()+" : "+node1.getFirstChild().getTextContent().trim());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line

```
if (node.getNodeName()=="GA") {
```

to

```
if (node.getTextContent().equals("GA")) {
```

There were two problems:

1. you compare the name, when you want to compare the content
2. you compare a String with ==, when Strings should be compared with .equals()

You can also simplify some thinsg (just one for loop)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\VAMSIKRISHNA\\Desktop\\Apache Poi\\appConfig.plist")));

    NodeList nodeList=document.getElementsByTagName("key");
    NodeList nodeList1=document.getElementsByTagName("string");

    for (int i=0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        Node node1 = nodeList1.item(i);
        if (node.getTextContent().startsWith("GA")) {
            String textOfChild = "";
            if(node1.getFirstChild() != null && node1.getFirstChild().getTextContent() != null) {
                textOfChild = node1.getFirstChild().getTextContent().trim();
            }
            System.out.println("Nodename"+node1.getNodeName()+" : "+ textOfChild);
        }
    }
}
```

Caveat: This does assume that you have the same number of key and string elements.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. I have reedited the code with ur changes. But its showing null pointer exception on the following line                                             System.out.println(node1.getFirstChild().getTextContent());

Comment: Glad I could help; you'll need to add a null check: if(node1.getFirstChild() != null)

Comment: I have added the null check to the code.

Comment: I have tried with your code But its showing the string value for the all elements. I have edited my xml file in above . Can you please check that once. I need the value specifically for google analystics

Comment: I'm still not getting the proper values after implementing your code. For ex if (node.getTextContent().equals("GAAnalytics")) I'm getting some other value –

Comment: Can you help me

Comment: Which output are you getting?

Comment: Nodenamestring : /4177/UCLA_iPhone
Nodenamestring : button

Comment: This value is not in the XML you have posted. Can you please post the complete XML file.

Comment: I did . check the edited xml

Comment: The value  /4177/UCLA_iPhone is not in the XML; is it possible that you parse a different xml file?

Comment: i have changed to UCLA to some other value  in the xml file

Comment: @JensS-  I have changed to UCLA to some other value in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

Your example XML does not match to your explanation and it is not valid xml.

```
<type>prod</type>
<dict></dict>
<key>GA</key>
<string>UA-111111-24</string>
```

You should go through all config elements of your list and then print the names and textcontent of the subelements.

Comment: thats the just sample lines from my xml file . I need to get the GA value as UA-111111-24. I was unable to get that . can you help me

Comment: Can you post the whole xml file?

Comment: Can you help me

Comment: I try to. See belohnt.

Comment: @Juliane-can you help me

Answer (score 0):

try node.getTextContent().equals("GA")

Please refer : https://www.javatpoint.com/string-comparison-in-java

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You first should look for the wrapping "dict" and then search the childs of this.

```
    NodeList dictList = document.getElementsByTagName("dict");
    for (int j = 0; j < dictList.getLength(); j++) {
        if (dictList.item(j) instanceof Element) {
            Element dict = (Element) dictList.item(j);

            NodeList nodeList = dict.getElementsByTagName("key");
            NodeList nodeList1 = dict.getElementsByTagName("string");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                if (node.getTextContent().equals("GAAnalyticsKey")) {
                    Node node1 = nodeList1.item(i);
                    System.out.println("Nodename" + node.getNodeName() + " : "
                            + node.getTextContent().trim() + " " + node1.getNodeName() + " : "
                            + node1.getTextContent().trim());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not getting the proper values after implementing your code. For ex if (node.getTextContent().equals("GAAnalytics")) I'm getting some other value

Comment: There are more "key" entries than "string" entries in your xml, so my first approach can not work. Try the last one.

Comment: I have tried with the following code. But iam not getting any output NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("key");
NodeList nodeList1 = document.getElementsByTagName("string");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
 
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        if (node.getTextContent().equals("GAAnalyticsKey")) {
            Node node1 = node.getNextSibling();
            System.out.println(
                     node1.getTextContent());
        }
}}

Comment: I'm still  not getting the proper values after implementing your code. For ex if (node.getTextContent().equals("GAAnalytics")) I'm getting some other value

Comment: Which value did you get? With the given data my code worked for me. The problem with the code of JensS is that you have more Keys than strings. Do you understand the differences between your original code, JensS and my Code?

Comment: I have edited the xml file and added more keys and strings . Can you check the code now.